# Joining multiple tables: where to filter efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a number of tables, around four, that I wish to join together. To make my code cleaner and readable (to me), I wish to join all at once and then filter at the end:

```
SELECT f1, f2, ..., fn
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.field = t2.field
        INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.field = t3.field
        INNER JOIN t4 ON t3.field = t4.field
WHERE // filters here
```

But I suspect that placing each table in subqueries and filtering in each scope would make performance better.

```
SELECT f1, f2, ..., fn
FROM (SELECT t1_f1, t1_f2, ..., t1_fi FROM t1 WHERE // filter here) AS a 
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT t2_f1, t2_f2, ..., t2_fj FROM t2 WHERE // filter here) AS b
     ON // and so on
```

Kindly advise which would lead to better performance and/or if my hunch is correct. I am willing to sacrifice performance to readability.

If indeed filtering in each subquery will be more efficient, does the architecture of database platform would make any difference or is this holds true for all RDBMS SQL flavors?

I'm using both SQL Server and Postgres.

Comment: Write readable code, the optimizer is supposed to take care of filtering order.

Comment: you can also use put the filter directly into the join condition: `FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.field = t2.field AND t2.column3 > 42`. But all three alternatives will most probably generate the same execution plan. But the **only** way to verify this, is to look at the execution plans (in both products)

Comment: For PosgresSQL or MySQL use EXPLAIN to get more information about how your query will be executed. SQL Server has graphical tool to display execution plan. To optimize SQL start from execution plan output

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara:in SQL Server you can also get a "plain text" execution plan if you want (similar to the one in Postgres or in XML). In fact it's not "SQL Server" that has a graphical tool but "SQL Server **Management Studio**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query optimizer will always attempt to take care of finding the most optimal plan from your SQL.

You should concentrate more on writing readable, maintainable code and then by analyzing the execution plan find the inefficient parts of your query (and more likely) the inefficient parts of your database and indexing design.

Moving your filtering around from the where clause to the join clause without any meaningful analysis is likely to be wasted effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach will always be better as the SQL engine will evaluate where conditions first and then perform joins. So while evaluating where clause, it will filter records if conditions are available.

```
SELECT f1, f2, ..., fn 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.field = t2.field
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.field = t3.field
    INNER JOIN t4 ON t3.field = t4.field
WHERE // filters here
```

Comment: This is simply not true (at least not  "in general" as you claim it to be). I wouldn't be surprised at all if both alternatives lead to the same execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

Join will always perform better if you have indexed properly.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.